# How to use iframe in Toloka project

Tags: iframe, toloka

Is there a way to use `iframe` to render the HTML views for users to provide judgments?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good requester’s guide for details on the component: https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/t-components/iframe.html